# Single word request: the person that "picks up things"

Tags: single-word-requests

A person who drives vehicles is a "driver"

A person who swims in the water is a "swimmer"

What do you call a person who goes around and picks things up? "pickuper"?

It would be someone who literally grabs a box on the ground and puts it somewhere else (at higher altitude) ie: from the ground to a truck or from the ground to a shelve

An example:

> A: I need to pick up these boxes
>   B: The *pickuper* will do it for you

Comment: ...a probationer?

Comment: that's some who is in probation or who has a job and is trained or is on trial, i'm talking about someone who literally grab something and pick it up

Comment: it was a joke: people who are out on probation are sometimes told to do a certain amount of litter-pickin'. Your question is very unclear: does this figurative person pick up lots of things, or are they an occasional  picker-upper? BTW, From the SWR tag: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE "

Comment: Are you talking about a picker in a warehouse, or a loader at a loading dock? Or maybe a stockboy?

Comment: Not exactly a picker in a warehouse, but someone really close to that

Comment: Guy, you gotta make this clear in the question: you cannot depend on the users to read ALL the comments to clarify what it is exactly that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I edited and added an example, hope that is enough

Comment: You need more context. *Why* do you need to pick up the boxes?

Comment: I'm modeling this actions of picking boxes (and move them) in software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about picker-up? Similarly passer-by or hanger-on

https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/compound-nouns/

Comment: or simply picker

Comment: I think that a picker is someone who "select" things, and not someone who "lifting things from the floor", but I see that "picker" it's used in some places

Comment: 'Picker-up' from 1670, 'picker-upper' from 1913.

Answer (score 2):

**loader**

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/loader):

*noun*
1. a person or thing that loads.

Example: "*The truck loaders will be here in half an hour.*"

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your sample sentence, collector would work. "The (box) collector" will do it for you. A "garbage collector" does exactly that.

Collector: "A person who collects things of a specified type." new Oxford American Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**Courier**

> 1. a company or employee of a company that transports commercial packages and documents.

**Carrier**

> 2. a person or company that undertakes the professional conveyance of goods or people